# JUnit tests hang on string.contains() in MessageQueue

Tags: java, android, junit4

I'm hoping someone can help here.  I had no problems with JUnit until I upgraded Android Studio 5.1RC. Suddenly my JUnit tests are hanging when I try to debug, which is incredibly frustrating.  Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: The code for the JUnit tests? As well as the code for what they are testing?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: if (sentence.contains("(")) pp_response=ParseParens(sentence);

Comment: Basically, any time String.contains(String string) is invoked, it hangs.

Comment: I'm testing methods that are not in my MainActivity yet

Comment: Okay, and when is it invoked? How is it invoked when it hangs? On what it is invoked? On what context is it invoked?